# Centralizer and Normalizer

Tags: group-theory

Let be $V\leq \mathrm{Aut}\left( G\right)$, $N\vartriangleleft G$ and $V$-invariant.
Consider the semidirect product $G\rtimes V$.

Let  $X$ be the preimage of $C_{G/N}\left( V\right) =\left\{
gN~;~g^{v}N=gN,\forall v\in V\right\} $ in $G$. Is it true that $X$ normalizes $NV$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the process of "accepting" answers to your questions? Look at [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/742) as a first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g\in X$. If $v\in V$, then we know that $vgv^{-1}N = gN$, so in particular there exists $n\in N$ such that $vgv^{-1}=gn$. Therefore, $vgv^{-1}g^{-1}=gng^{-1} = n'$ for some $n'\in N$ (since $N\triangleleft G$), so $gv^{-1}g^{-1} = v^{-1}n' = (v^{-1}n'v)v^{-1}=n''v^{-1}$ for some $n''\in N$.

Therefore, for every $n\in N$ and $v\in V$ we have 
$$g(nv^{-1})g^{-1} = \Bigl(gng^{-1}\Bigr)\Bigl( gv^{-1}g^{-1}\Bigr) = n'''n''v^{-1}\in NV.$$

Comment: Are we considering $X\leq N_{G}\left( NV\right) $ either $X\leq N_{G\rtimes V}\left( NV\right) $? Great solution!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You said that $X$ is the preimage of $N_{G/N}(V)$ in $(G\rtimes V)/N$. We are showing that in fact $X\subseteq N_G(NV)$ in $G\rtimes V$. Of course, $N_G(NV)\subseteq N_{G\rtimes V}(NV)$, but that is automatic: if $K,H,L$ are subgroups of a group $G$, and $H\subseteq L$, then $N_H(K) \subseteq N_L(K)$.

Comment: I understood! Thank you!